# Excel VBA - Major Unit Scale in minutes

Tags: excel, vba, charts, scale

Is there a way to set the Major Unit Scale in minutes? The begin and end time doesn't matter. Example:

```
00:00 00:01 00:02 00:03 00:04
Horizotal axis ->
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

Type this:
YourChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 1 / (24 * 60)

Now the scale for the horizontal axis is set to minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just format the cells the axis refers to as minute.

```
Worksheets("MySheetName").Range("A2:A16").NumberFormat = "hh:mm;@"
```

*Note: A2:A16 are the cells the axis refers to.*

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough. I load from a csv file log data to excel. Then I calculate the source range with VBA for the charts. De column with the time in it skips sometimes a x amount of minutes. I want to set the .majoruntiscale to minutes so that it doesn't look like this: 00:03 00:06 00:09.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to add information to your question.

Comment: As I said you need to format the cells that way you want the axis to be formatted. The axis uses the same format as the cells.

Comment: Yes, but the horizontal axis doesn't increment each time with 1.